# Problemas con un bucle for (python)

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de crear un programa como reto personal, que genera un sudoku desde 0, totalmente aleatorio. Pero hay un bucle for que me está dando muchos problemas ya que he depurado el código paso a paso varias veces, pero cada vez falla en una iteración diferente. También lo he repasado varias veces línea por línea pero no soy capaz de encontrar ningún error. He de decir que soy principiante en esto de la programación.

El código en cuestión:

```
from random import randint

def obtenerNums():
```

A continuación creo 9 listas con 9 items que representan cada cuadrado del sudoku(Cu = cuadrado).

```
    CuA = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
    CuB = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
    CuC = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
    CuD = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
    CuE = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
    CuF = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
    CuG = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
    CuH = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
    CuI = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

A continuación genero una lista de números del uno al 9 totalmente aleatorios

```
    numA = randint(1, 9)
    numB = randint(1, 9)
    while numB == numA:
        numB = randint(1, 9)
    numC = randint(1, 9)
    while numC == numA or numC == numB:
        numC = randint(1, 9)
    numD = randint(1, 9)
    while numD == numA or numD == numB or numD == numC:
        numD = randint(1, 9)
    numE = randint(1, 9)
    while numE == numA or numE == numB or numE == numC or numE == numD:
        numE = randint(1, 9)
    numF = randint(1, 9)
    while numF == numA or numF == numB or numF == numC or numF == numD or numF == numE:
        numF = randint(1, 9)
    numG = randint(1, 9)
    while numG == numA or numG == numB or numG == numC or numG == numD or numG == numE or numG == numF:
        numG = randint(1, 9)
    numH = randint(1, 9)
    while numH == numA or numH == numB or numH == numC or numH == numD or numH == numE or numH == numF or numH == numG:
        numH = randint(1, 9)
    numI = randint(1, 9)
    while numI == numA or numI == numB or numI == numC or numI == numD or numI == numE or numI == numF or numI == numG or numI == numH:
        numI = randint(1, 9)

    listaNums = [numA, numB, numC, numD, numE, numF, numG, numH, numI]
```

Y a continuación el bucle for, en el que utilizo tres funciones:

- "ocupado(Cu,indice)": Devuelve True si el índice en cuestión esta ocupado.
- "queFila(Cu,indice)": Devuelve un string que indica en que fila está el índice en cuestión "Fila A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I.
- "queColumn(cuadrado,indice)": Devuelve un string que indica en que columna está el índice en cuestión "Fila A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I.

```
    for num in listaNums:
        # CUADRADO A
        indexCuA = randint(0, 8)
        while ocupado(CuA, indexCuA):
            indexCuA = randint(0, 8)
        CuA[indexCuA] = num
        # CUADRADO B
        FilaCuA = queFila('CuA', indexCuA)
        indexCuB = randint(0, 8)
        FilaCuB = queFila('CuB', indexCuB)
        while ocupado(CuB, indexCuB) or FilaCuA == FilaCuB:
            indexCuB = randint(0, 8)
            FilaCuB = queFila('CuB', indexCuB)
        CuB[indexCuB] = num
        # CUADRADO C
        FilaCuA = queFila('CuA', indexCuA)
        FilaCuB = queFila('CuB', indexCuB)
        indexCuC = randint(0, 8)
        FilaCuC = queFila('CuC', indexCuC)
        while ocupado(CuC, indexCuC) or FilaCuA == FilaCuC or FilaCuB == FilaCuC:
            indexCuC = randint(0, 8)
            FilaCuC = queFila('CuC', indexCuC)
        CuC[indexCuC] = num
        # CUADRADO D
        ColCuA = queColumn('CuA', indexCuA)
        indexCuD = randint(0, 8)
        ColCuD = queColumn('CuD', indexCuD)
        while ocupado(CuD, indexCuD) or ColCuA == ColCuD:
            indexCuD = randint(0, 8)
            ColCuD = queFila('CuD', indexCuD)
        CuD[indexCuD] = num
        # CUADRADO E
        ColCuB = queColumn('CuB', indexCuB)
        FilaCuD = queFila('CuD', indexCuD)
        indexCuE = randint(0, 8)
        ColCuE = queColumn('CuE', indexCuE)
        FilaCuE = queFila('CuE', indexCuE)
        while ocupado(CuE, indexCuE) or ColCuB == ColCuE or FilaCuD == FilaCuE:
            indexCuE = randint(0, 8)
            ColCuE = queColumn('CuE', indexCuE)
            FilaCuE = queFila('CuE', indexCuE)
        CuE[indexCuE] = num
        # CUADRADO F
        ColCuC = queColumn('CuC', indexCuC)
        FilaCuD = queFila('CuD', indexCuD)
        FilaCuE = queFila('CuE', indexCuE)
        indexCuF = randint(0, 8)
        ColCuF = queColumn('CuF', indexCuF)
        FilaCuF = queFila('CuF', indexCuF)
        while ocupado(CuF, indexCuF) or ColCuC == ColCuF or FilaCuD == FilaCuF or FilaCuE == FilaCuF:
            indexCuF = randint(0, 8)
            ColCuF = queColumn('CuF', indexCuF)
            FilaCuF = queFila('CuF', indexCuF)
        CuF[indexCuF] = num
        # CUADRADO G
        ColCuA = queColumn('CuA', indexCuA)
        ColCuD = queColumn('CuD', indexCuD)
        indexCuG = randint(0, 8)
        ColCuG = queColumn('CuG', indexCuG)
        while ocupado(CuG, indexCuG) or ColCuA == ColCuG or ColCuD == ColCuG:
            indexCuG = randint(0, 8)
            ColCuG = queColumn('CuG', indexCuG)
        CuG[indexCuG] = num
        # CUADRADO H
        ColCuB = queColumn('CuB', indexCuB)
        ColCuE = queColumn('CuE', indexCuE)
        FilaCuG = queFila('CuG', indexCuG)
        indexCuH = randint(0, 8)
        ColCuH = queColumn('CuH', indexCuH)
        FilaCuH = queFila('CuH', indexCuH)
        while ocupado(CuH, indexCuH) or ColCuB == ColCuH or ColCuE == ColCuH or FilaCuG == FilaCuH:
            indexCuH = randint(0, 8)
            ColCuH = queColumn('CuH', indexCuH)
            FilaCuH = queFila('CuH', indexCuH)
        CuH[indexCuH] = num
        # CUADRADO I
        ColCuC = queColumn('CuC', indexCuC)
        ColCuF = queColumn('CuF', indexCuF)
        FilaCuG = queFila('CuG', indexCuG)
        FilaCuH = queFila('CuH', indexCuH)
        indexCuI = randint(0, 8)
        ColCuI = queColumn('CuI', indexCuI)
        FilaCuI = queFila('CuI', indexCuI)
        while ocupado(CuI, indexCuI) or ColCuC == ColCuI or ColCuF == ColCuI or FilaCuG == FilaCuI or FilaCuH == FilaCuI:
            indexCuI = randint(0, 8)
            ColCuI = queColumn('CuI', indexCuI)
            FilaCuI = queFila('CuI', indexCuI)
        CuI[indexCuI] = num
```

Función ocupado():

```
    def ocupado(Cu, index):
        if Cu[index] != '':
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Función queFila():

```
    def queFila(Cua, index):

        Cu = Cua
        if Cu == 'CuA':
            if str(index) in '012':
                return 'FilaA'
            elif str(index) in '345':
                return 'FilaB'
            if str(index) in '678':
                return 'FilaC'

        elif Cu == 'CuB':
            if str(index) in '012':
                return 'FilaA'
            elif str(index) in '345':
                return 'FilaB'
            if str(index) in '678':
                return 'FilaC'

        elif Cu == 'CuC':
            if str(index) in '012':
                return 'FilaA'
            elif str(index) in '345':
                return 'FilaB'
            if str(index) in '678':
                return 'FilaC'

        elif Cu == 'CuD':
            if str(index) in '012':
                return 'FilaD'
            elif str(index) in '345':
                return 'FilaE'
            if str(index) in '678':
                return 'FilaF'

        elif Cu == 'CuE':
            if str(index) in '012':
                return 'FilaD'
            elif str(index) in '345':
                return 'FilaE'
            if str(index) in '678':
                return 'FilaF'

        elif Cu == 'CuF':
            if str(index) in '012':
                return 'FilaD'
            elif str(index) in '345':
                return 'FilaE'
            if str(index) in '678':
                return 'FilaF'

        elif Cu == 'CuG':
            if str(index) in '012':
                return 'FilaG'
            elif str(index) in '345':
                return 'FilaH'
            if str(index) in '678':
                return 'FilaI'

        elif Cu == 'CuH':
            if str(index) in '012':
                return 'FilaG'
            elif str(index) in '345':
                return 'FilaH'
            if str(index) in '678':
                return 'FilaI'

        elif Cu == 'CuI':
            if str(index) in '012':
                return 'FilaG'
            elif str(index) in '345':
                return 'FilaH'
            if str(index) in '678':
                return 'FilaI'
```

Función queColumn():

```
    def queColumn(Cua, index):

        Cu = Cua
        if Cu == 'CuA':
            if str(index) in '036':
                return 'ColA'
            elif str(index) in '147':
                return 'ColB'
            if str(index) in '258':
                return 'ColC'

        elif Cu == 'CuB':
            if str(index) in '036':
                return 'ColD'
            elif str(index) in '147':
                return 'ColE'
            if str(index) in '258':
                return 'ColF'

        elif Cu == 'CuC':
            if str(index) in '036':
                return 'ColG'
            elif str(index) in '147':
                return 'ColH'
            if str(index) in '258':
                return 'ColI'

        elif Cu == 'CuD':
            if str(index) in '036':
                return 'ColA'
            elif str(index) in '147':
                return 'ColB'
            if str(index) in '258':
                return 'ColC'

        elif Cu == 'CuE':
            if str(index) in '036':
                return 'ColD'
            elif str(index) in '147':
                return 'ColE'
            if str(index) in '258':
                return 'ColF'

        elif Cu == 'CuF':
            if str(index) in '036':
                return 'ColG'
            elif str(index) in '147':
                return 'ColH'
            if str(index) in '258':
                return 'ColI'

        elif Cu == 'CuG':
            if str(index) in '036':
                return 'ColA'
            elif str(index) in '147':
                return 'ColB'
            if str(index) in '258':
                return 'ColC'

        elif Cu == 'CuH':
            if str(index) in '036':
                return 'ColD'
            elif str(index) in '147':
                return 'ColE'
            if str(index) in '258':
                return 'ColF'

        elif Cu == 'CuI':
            if str(index) in '036':
                return 'ColG'
            elif str(index) in '147':
                return 'ColH'
            if str(index) in '258':
                return 'ColI'
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual seria el problema?

Comment: o sea "pero cada vez falla en una iteración diferente" esto que quiere decir? tira un error? si tira un error, cual es el error?

Comment: Cuando lo ejecuto normal el codigo se queda como cargando, y cuando lo estoy depurando derepente en una de las iteraciones se corta.

Comment: Sin avisar de ningun error simplemente se corta.

Comment: Aún no entiendo muy bien qué estás intentando hacer en tu bucle pero como aporte te diré que lo que haces para declarar `listaNums` es bastante retorcido. Puedes hacer `listaNums = list(range(1, 10))` y luego utilizar `shuffle` del módulo `random`: `random.shuffle(listaNums)`

Comment: Qué hace la función `ocupado()`?

Comment: @CésarGonzález
La función ocupado lo que hace es verificar si el índice de la lista que le paso por parámetro es diferente a ('') (un string vacío), lo que significa que el bucle ya ha asignado un número en el índice de dicha  lista.

Comment: @marimag puedes copiar también las funciones `ocupado()`, `queFila()` y `queCloumn()`? no entiendo por qué estás pasando un string como parámetro en las dos últimas y la variable en cuestión en la primera

Comment: Lo que intentento hacer con bucle es crear el sudoku partiendo de 0, es decir en la primera iteración el bucle coge el primer número de "listaNums" y escoge un índice random para elcuadrado A. Para cuadrado B vuelve a escoger un índice random, pero este no puede estar en misma fila que el índice del cuadrado A, en el cuadrado C no puede estar en la misma fila que en el cuadrado A ni en el B, en el D no puede estar en la misma columna que en el cuadrado A y asi sucesivamente. Con el primer número la función ocupado no hace falta pero con el resto sí.

Comment: He estructurado el tablero del sudoku por filas (horizontales) de la A a la I de arriba a abajo, las columnas de la A a la I de izquierda a derecha, y los cuadrados de la A a la I siendo el cuadrado A el de la esquina superior izquierda, el B el cuadrado del centro superior, el C el de la esquina superior derecha, el D el del centro al lado izquierdo, el E el que está en medio, el F el que se encuentra en medio al lado derecho, el G el de la esquina inferior izquierda, el H el del centro inferior y el I el de la esquina inferior derecha.

Comment: Creo que el problema reside en cómo estás rellenando el sudoku. Llega un momento en el que el sudoku no tiene solución ya que no hay forma de colocar un número en ninguna posición, por lo que no sale de los `while`

Comment: @CésarGonzález Pero ¿eso no debería suceder en la última iteración del código?

Comment: No tiene por qué, puede darse la situación en cualquier momento, pero cuanto más lleno esté el tablero más fácil será que ocurra. Como consejo para que replantees el algoritmo puedes pensar primero en cómo rellenar cuadrados que no entren en conflicto (CuA, CuE y CuI por ejemplo) y luego rellenar el resto. Echa un vistazo a [esta entrada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471152/how-to-create-a-sudoku-puzzle-in-python) donde se plantean diferentes alternativas